# Como eu mudo uma 2ª imagem fixa ao passar o mouse sobre 1ª imagem?

Tags: html, css

Para explicar melhor, eu gostaria de mudar uma 2ª imagem conforme eu passo o mouse sobre a 1ª.

#### Exemplo:

Situação onde não passa nenhum mouse sobre a 1ª imagem.

[image: Outmouse]
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Quando eu passar o mouse sobre a 1ª imagem, a 2ª altera

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Com isso, quando eu passo o mouse em cima de uma palavra a cada a secunda imagem é alterada.

Eu usava esse código para 1 imagem inteira alterar ela mesma, só que a representação das cores ficou estranha, apareceu mais de uma do que outra como podem ver abaixo;

```html
<html><article><img src= "https://i.imgur.com/T7CkXGw.png"
onMouseOver= this.src="https://i.imgur.com/9EDK5EA.png"
onMouseOut= this.src="https://i.imgur.com/T7CkXGw.png"
onClick=location="https://centrorpg.com/index.php?topic=22835.msg161154;topicseen#post_elmos"><div>
<img src= "https://i.imgur.com/8LoUSqQ.png"
onMouseOver= this.src="https://i.imgur.com/nDLa00P.png"
onMouseOut= this.src="https://i.imgur.com/8LoUSqQ.png"
onClick=location="https://centrorpg.com/index.php?topic=22835.msg161154;topicseen#post_armaduras"><div>
<img src= "https://i.imgur.com/xTL0Htn.png"
onMouseOver= this.src="https://i.imgur.com/KcwPPnx.png"
onMouseOut= this.src="https://i.imgur.com/xTL0Htn.png"
onClick=location="https://centrorpg.com/index.php?topic=22835.msg161154;topicseen#post_espadas"><div><img src= "https://i.imgur.com/oYn97Sr.png"onMouseOver= this.src="https://i.imgur.com/G9PS5nU.png"
onMouseOut= this.src="https://i.imgur.com/oYn97Sr.png"
onClick=location="https://centrorpg.com/index.php?topic=22835.msg161154;topicseen#post_escudos"><div><img src= "https://i.imgur.com/nJFZqBs.png"
onMouseOver= this.src="https://i.imgur.com/fULOFTE.png"
onMouseOut= this.src="https://i.imgur.com/nJFZqBs.png"
onClick=location="https://centrorpg.com/index.php?topic=22835.msg161154;topicseen#post_acessorios"><div></article></html>
```

#### Edição: 03/09/2019 14:23

Para explicar melhor o que estou precisando:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/wggwW.png
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

#### Novo código, resolvido.

```css
<html>
<head>
<style>
.container {
    margin: auto;
    height: 184px;
    width: 288px;
    position: relative;
}
.container img {
    display: block;
}
.container img:nth-child(n+6) {
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
}
.overx {
    z-index: 2;
}
.elmo:hover ~ .elmox {
    z-index: 2;
}
.colete:hover ~ .coletex {
    z-index: 2;
}
.espada:hover ~ .espadax {
    z-index: 2;
}
.escudo:hover ~ .escudox {
    z-index: 2;
}
.acessorio:hover ~ .acessoriox {
    z-index: 2;
}</style></head>

<div class="container">
    <img class="elmo" src="https://i.imgur.com/mBmYJzd.png" onClick=location="https://centrorpg.com/index.php?topic=22835.msg161158;topicseen#post_elmos">
    <img class="colete" src="https://i.imgur.com/cbTwy0A.png" onClick=location="https://centrorpg.com/index.php?topic=22835.msg161158;topicseen#post_armaduras">
    <img class="espada" src="https://i.imgur.com/uhn3zj2.png" onClick=location="https://centrorpg.com/index.php?topic=22835.msg161158;topicseen#post_espadas">
    <img class="escudo" src="https://i.imgur.com/KlDt4yo.png" onClick=location="https://centrorpg.com/index.php?topic=22835.msg161158;topicseen#post_escudos">
    <img class="acessorio" src="https://i.imgur.com/UfpdOnV.png" onClick=location="https://centrorpg.com/index.php?topic=22835.msg161158;topicseen#post_acessorios">

    <img class="overx" src="https://i.imgur.com/LMejPvW.png">
    <img class="elmox" src="https://i.imgur.com/LnIcqKD.png">
    <img class="coletex" src="https://i.imgur.com/n3OWgbY.png">
    <img class="espadax" src="https://i.imgur.com/BmvosVk.png">
    <img class="escudox" src="https://i.imgur.com/87CjNwg.png">
    <img class="acessoriox" src="https://i.imgur.com/fngGeHd.png">
</div></html>
```

Comment: Como assim, apareceu mais de um do que de outra? não entendi muito bem

Comment: Cara mas seu código já parece funcionar... o que vc quer é tirar esse espaço em branco entre uma imagem e outra?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cara como parece algo bem simples e que não vai ficar mudando aqui tem um exemplo só com CSS, vc vai ter 3 imagens a esquerda, e 3 imagens grandes a direita, sendo que as imagens da direita estão com `position:absolute`, uma sobre as outras. Com isso quando vc fizer o `:hover` na imagem correspondente da esquerda vc muda o `z-indez` da imagem da direita deixando ela a vista. Para fazer essa dinâmica vc vai precisar do seletor `~`.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Para entender melhor veja o código abaixo

```css
.container {
    height: 300px;
    width: 200px;
    border: 1px solid #000;
    position: relative;
}
.container img {
    display: block;
}
.container img:nth-child(n+4) {
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
}
.elmox {
    z-index: 2;
}
.elmo:hover ~ .elmox {
    z-index: 2;
}
.colete:hover ~ .coletex {
    z-index: 2;
}
.espada:hover ~ .espadax {
    z-index: 2;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <img class="elmo" src="https://unsplash.it/100/100">
    <img class="colete" src="https://unsplash.it/100/100/?city">
    <img class="espada" src="https://unsplash.it/100/100/?animals">

    <img class="elmox" src="https://unsplash.it/100/300/?car">
    <img class="coletex" src="https://unsplash.it/100/300/?nature">
    <img class="espadax" src="https://unsplash.it/100/300/?people">
</div>
```

Comment: Obrigado a Ana que tentou ajudar e ao Hugocsl que resolveu usando por meio do CSS, preciso estudar mais esse CSS.

O código agora esta funcionando perfeitamente, gostaria de implementar a mudança no post principal, para quem precisar.

Obrigado novamente aos dois. :)

Comment: @VictorSena valeu jovem, que bom que ajudou. CSS resolve muita coisa sem precisar apelar pro JS rss... Estude sim esse código vai te ajudar em outras situações. Abs

Answer (score 3):

Nao sei se percebi bem a questão :/
Pretendes ter duas imagens separadas e o mouseover numa imagem mudar a segunda imagem?

Se assim for tens de nos eventos em vez de utilizar `this.` utilizar uma forma de seleccionar a imagem que pretendes alterar, por exemplo através de `document.getElementById(id_imagem_a_alterar)`.

exemplo, duplicando a imagem que deste: 
(ao passar o rato na 1ª vais alterar a 2ª, consoante o id atribuido aos pedaços da imagem)

```html
<html>
<img src= "https://i.imgur.com/T7CkXGw.png"
onMouseOver= document.getElementById('i1').src="https://i.imgur.com/9EDK5EA.png"
onMouseOut= document.getElementById('i1').src="https://i.imgur.com/T7CkXGw.png"
onClick=location="https://centrorpg.com/index.php?topic=22835.msg161154;topicseen#post_elmos">
<div>
<img src= "https://i.imgur.com/8LoUSqQ.png"
onMouseOver= document.getElementById('i2').src="https://i.imgur.com/nDLa00P.png"
onMouseOut= document.getElementById('i2').src="https://i.imgur.com/8LoUSqQ.png"
onClick=location="https://centrorpg.com/index.php?topic=22835.msg161154;topicseen#post_armaduras">
<div>
<img src= "https://i.imgur.com/xTL0Htn.png"
onMouseOver= document.getElementById('i3').src="https://i.imgur.com/KcwPPnx.png"
onMouseOut= document.getElementById('i3').src="https://i.imgur.com/xTL0Htn.png"
onClick=location="https://centrorpg.com/index.php?topic=22835.msg161154;topicseen#post_espadas">
<div>
<img src= "https://i.imgur.com/oYn97Sr.png"
onMouseOver= document.getElementById('i4').src="https://i.imgur.com/G9PS5nU.png"
onMouseOut= document.getElementById('i4').src="https://i.imgur.com/oYn97Sr.png"
onClick=location="https://centrorpg.com/index.php?topic=22835.msg161154;topicseen#post_escudos">
<div>
<img src= "https://i.imgur.com/nJFZqBs.png"
onMouseOver= document.getElementById('i5').src="https://i.imgur.com/fULOFTE.png"
onMouseOut= document.getElementById('i5').src="https://i.imgur.com/nJFZqBs.png"
onClick=location="https://centrorpg.com/index.php?topic=22835.msg161154;topicseen#post_acessorios">
<div>


<img id='i1' src= "https://i.imgur.com/T7CkXGw.png">
<div>
<img id='i2' src= "https://i.imgur.com/8LoUSqQ.png">
<div>
<img id='i3' src= "https://i.imgur.com/xTL0Htn.png">
<div>
<img id='i4' src= "https://i.imgur.com/oYn97Sr.png">
<div>
<img id='i5' src= "https://i.imgur.com/nJFZqBs.png">
<div>
</article>

</html>
```

Comment: Sim, exatamente.
Eu coloquei uma imagem na pergunta principal explicando melhor: https://i.imgur.com/1Os6QEj.png